# VIM - how to delete all lines inside a php tag?

Tags: vim

I would like to know how to delete :

all of the contents inside a php tag using vim

```
<?php i want to delete this ?>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've tried di< but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your opening & closing PHP tags (`<?php ... ?>`) are in the same line, you can do it this way.

1. Put your cursor at the first character after PHP opening tag.
2. Type **`v/ ?[enter]d`** in normal mode.

The 2nd point means to **enters visual mode ('v')** from the first character, **searches ('/')** for the **[space]? (' ?')** pattern (exactly before the PHP closing tag), and then **delete it ('d')**.

Answer (score 2):

Use `di< or di>` to delete all the characters inside `<>`. The cursor should be inside of the `<>`.

Use `ci< or ci>` to delete and be in insert mode.

**Helpful but Optional Explanation:**
It is better to start with text-objects. Excerpt from `:h text-objects`, given below, suggest two forms `i` and `a`

> This is a series of commands that can only be used while in Visual mode or
>   after an operator.  The commands that start with "a" select "a"n object
>   including white space, the commands starting with "i" select an "inner" object
>   without white space, or just the white space.  Thus the "inner" commands                                                                    always select less text than the "a" commands.

text-objects are useful to **other character pair like `(), {}, etc`**. For example, it is useful while changing

```
if ( i == true ) {
}
```

to

```
if (_) {
}
```

by using `ci(` or `ci)`.

Comment: "i" means inner (could apply to other "text-objects") read the help on this topic: `:h text-objects`

Comment: Thanks, added description based on your comment